# Error applying Portuguese characters Times New Roman on Word Open openxml c#

Tags: c#, openxml

Text example (Portuguese): PROCURAÇÃO

```
RunProperties runProperties0 = new RunProperties();
var runFont0 = new RunFonts { Ascii = "Arial" };
var size0 = new FontSize { Val = new StringValue("24") };
runProperties0.Append(new Bold());
runProperties0.Append(new Underline() { Val = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.UnderlineValues.Single });
//runProperties0.Append(runFont0);
runProperties0.Append(size0);
```

I was expecting "PROCURAÇÃO" in Times New Roman but I get "PROCURAÇÃO" where **ÇÃ** is returned as Calibri(Corpo).

How to apply the Times New Roman even for special Portuguese characters.

Thanks!

Code here:

```
public static void CreateWordprocessingDocument_teste(string filepath)
    {
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
            WordprocessingDocument.Create(filepath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

            mainPart.Document = new Document();
            Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());


            Text text0 = new Text() { Text = "PROCURAÇÃO", Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve };


            Run run0 = new Run();

            Paragraph para0 = new Paragraph();

            ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties0 = new ParagraphProperties();
            SpacingBetweenLines spaceBetweenLines0 = new SpacingBetweenLines();
            ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId0 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Normal" };
            Justification justification0 = new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Center };
            ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties0 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();

            paragraphProperties0.Append(paragraphStyleId0);
            paragraphProperties0.Append(justification0);
            paragraphProperties0.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties0);

            RunProperties runProperties0 = new RunProperties();
            var size0 = new FontSize { Val = new StringValue("24") };
            var runFont0 = new RunFonts { Ascii = "Times New Roman" };
            runProperties0.Append(new Bold());
            runProperties0.Append(new Underline() { Val = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.UnderlineValues.Single });
            runProperties0.Append(runFont0);
            runProperties0.Append(size0);

            run0.Append(runProperties0);
            run0.Append(text0);
            para0.Append(paragraphProperties0);
            para0.Append(run0);

            body.AppendChild(para0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I mean: var runFont0 = new RunFonts { Ascii = "Times New Roman" };

Comment: Where's the code that adds `PROCURAÇÃO`? What you posted configures `RunProperties` but never applies it to anything. Word doesn't care about Portuguese nor would it try to use a specific font based on the language. Word uses Unicode so *all* characters are the same. There's nothing special about those characters, in fact they're part of Latin1, what most people erroneously call ANSI or ASCII

Comment: Hi Panagiotis! I add the code as an example! Thanks for your return.

Comment: that's what you get when you try to use Times New Roman for anything in 2023 :-)

Comment: The problem is that this problem happens with other fonts too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is using `Ascii` on the `RunFonts` properties. As per the documentation, this font assignment applies to the

> first 128 Unicode code points

only (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.runfonts?view=openxml-2.8.1)

So while Ç and Ã are Latin1 characters, they are not plain ASCII. Assign the font to the entire glyph run, not only to those characters of it that are plain ASCII.

If you must use `RunFonts` for some reason, the easiest solution appears to be using all four properties ascii, highansi, complex and eastasian and set them to the same font.

Comment: I don't like questions with an accepted answer to be closed as "needs debugging details", so I voted to reopen this question.